# SUM and COUNT for kind of hierarchical data without ID relationship

Tags: sql, oracle12c, hierarchical

I have one table with items, date in year/month format and amout of each item sold on particular month and year.

There are coupl of items but there is also a relationship between some of them.
Items with relationship have same 3 characters
example : 101 is the item1 in basic version then later on came new version on the market 101AA and later 101AB which is still on the market = yearmonth 202102.
Not always the item needs to come with the basic version (3 characters only) but it can starts with the highest one = item 200A. later on came new version 200AC and later 200DD and as you can see there could be 2 versions on the market at th same time till now.

What I need is to display the first version of particular items , total months spend on market(all versions together) with total amount(all versions together) for those items only that are still present on the market.It is something like hierachical query with manager of department on top with its employees + all their salaries.
The last item 400AA was sold out on dec.2020 so it doesn't meet the condition.

the desired output should be as follows.

```
Item       months      total
101         26          260
200A        11          175




create table items (
yearmonth varchar2(6),
item_code varchar2(12),
amount number        );

insert into items values ( '201901' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '201902' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '201903' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '201904' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '201905' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '201906' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '201907' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '201908' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '201909' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '201910' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '201911' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '201912' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202001' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202002' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202003' , '101' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202004' , '101AA' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202005' , '101AA' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202006' , '101AA' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202007' , '101AA' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202008' , '101AA' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202009' , '101AA' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202010' , '101AA' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202011' , '101AB' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202012' , '101AB' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202101' , '101AB' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202102' , '101AB' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202004' , '200A' , 5 );
insert into items values ( '202005' , '200A' , 5 );
insert into items values ( '202006' , '200A' , 5 );
insert into items values ( '202007' , '200A' , 5 );
insert into items values ( '202008' , '200AC' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202009' , '200AC' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202010' , '200AC' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202011' , '200AC' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202011' , '200DD' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202012' , '200AC' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202012' , '200DD' , 25 );
insert into items values ( '202101' , '200AC' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202101' , '200DD' , 25 );
insert into items values ( '202102' , '200AC' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202102' , '200DD' , 25 );
insert into items values ( '202011' , '400' , 50 );
insert into items values ( '202011' , '400AA' , 10 );
insert into items values ( '202012' , '400AA' , 50 );
insert into items values ( '202012' , '400AA' , 25 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on above data, no need to use hierarchy queries, you can use below sql:

```
select ITEM_CODE_First,count(distinct YEARMONTH), sum(amount) total from(
select YEARMONTH,max(YEARMONTH)over (partition by substr(item_code,1,3)) as YEARMONTH_LAST,
ITEM_CODE, min(ITEM_CODE) over (partition by substr(item_code,1,3)) as ITEM_CODE_First,amount from items)
where YEARMONTH_LAST = 202102
group by ITEM_CODE_First;
```